# Find the <th> of a clicked <td> in a table when <th> has span greater than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to find a TD's associated TH cell, but am having trouble using JQuery's `index()` and `eq()` functions since the TH's in my table have spans of greater than one.

I know I can retrieve a TD's cellIndex property, but would I use this to find the TH? Or is there another more appropriate way?

Intended functionality is to click a cell and have it give me the name of the heading it's under. Code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/KyTDA/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the corresponding table header given the index of a table cell you can use the following jQuery (this is assuming you already have the table cell's index):

```
var th = td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index());
```

Comment: Thanks -- will this work even if the table headers have spans, therefore don't directory correspond to the indexes of the table cells?

Comment: @zeedog - The fact that your table headers have spans won't matter since the selector is just searching for table headers.  Any children elements of the table header won't be included in that selector.  What do you mean by directory?

Comment: If you have a single TH with a span of three, its index is 0. The TD's below it have indexes of 0, 1 and 2. Therefore, when you're trying to use the index of the TD elements to find the TH, they won't line up with the TH since there is no TH with index > 0.

Comment: @zeedog - It's much more beneficial if you just post the actual markup your working with versus explaining it.  You can edit your original post and update the question if you need.

Comment: sorry for not doing this the first time.

Comment: @zeedog - I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've edited your question and provided code, I'll provide another answer to this.

The markup you have posted isn't valid.  You don't have any table rows, and if you're trying to nest table cells inside table headings, that isn't valid either.  What are you trying to achieve in terms of layout?  Try going to http://jsfiddle.net/ and create your markup and then provide a link and let me know when you have the layout you're trying to create.

Comment: Basic layout example: http://jsfiddle.net/KyTDA/

I want to be able to click a cell and have it tell me the heading it is under.